# Why does rtrim remove things that aren't on the right?

Tags: php

```
$word = "shshsh.shshsh";
print(rtrim($word, "sh."));
```

Output is an empty string when I would have expected it to output the entire string (since "sh." does not appear at the end in this case).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php says of the "character mask" second option which you have specified as "sh."... _You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped_ . So basically you've told it to strip all the characters which appear in the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `"sh."` is a set of characters rather than a string to remove. It'll remove characters from the end of the `$word` recursively as long as it's a character in `[s, h, .]`, until it hits one that isn't in this list, essentially removing everything in your case.

Comment: Holy moly. That's a confusing way to specify a character mask! I'm sure I'm not the first person to misunderstand that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php), the 2nd parameter to `rtrim` will specify a character mask to remove from the string. In other words, by specifying `".sh"` as your character mask, you will remove all instances of `.`, `s`, and `h` separately, yielding the empty string.